# App Icon shows fine in Simulator, but when running on iPhone, Launch Image is shown as icon instead of the desired icon

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

my app icon shows fine in the IOS simulator and the launch image is displayed too. However, when I run the app on my iPhone 4, it shows the launch image as the app icon.

If I delete the .plist value for the launch image, this seems to resolve the problem for running on the iPhone. But should I be doing this?

Is there some setting I need to change on my phone? I have tried cleaning the project to no avail-- only deleting the plist Default.png value seems to fix the issue and I am not comfortable doing this because I figure xcode must copy it there for a reason.

System Details:

IOS 5.1
Xcode 4.3.3 (was a problem with 4.3.2 too though)
iPhone 4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your icon named Icon.png (and its associated Icon@2x.png, etc.)? This is the required name for iPhone apps according to the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html).

Comment: The icon is named Icon.png, that is not the issue. The only thing that seems to work is deleting Default.png from the .plist. Does your version of xcode place an entry for Default.png as an icon in your plist?

Comment: As far as I know it does not. It is not in my app's plist.

Comment: Ok, so I guess my real question is why is Xcode putting my launch image Default.png in my plist automatically? I have installed Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: Did you add the image in "Launch images" under Summary in the project? I wonder if manually setting it there adds it to the plist. Xcode should just detect Default.png and display it there automatically.

Comment: Yes, I added it in Launch images by manually dropping the image under Summary. And, yes that does add it to the plist. Your method of simply copying and letting Xcode detect does not add it to the plist, but Xcode does detect it. With your method, it runs fine on my phone. Thanks! I am guessing I have discovered a bug with my manual copying?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me; there is a way to submit it to Apple but I've never needed to do so.